# Python Bleak start_notify callback not invoked

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I tried to connect my ble device using Python bleak module. The device is getting scanned and connected. I try to enable notification for one of the characteristic using start_notify function.

```
await client.start_notify(notify_char,notify_callback)
def notify_callback(handle, data):
       print(handle, data)
```

The notify_callback function is not getting invoked.

Any pointers on how to get data notified continously from ble.

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your question to include more code. Ideally a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The [example](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#bleak.backends.client.BaseBleakClient.start_notify) in the docs doesn't have the await. To debug, use [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to check that your BLE device gives notifictions.

Comment: Or write a client to work with the [BLE Peripheral Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral&hl=en_GB&gl=US) to check you have Bleak working correctly.

Comment: `import asyncio
import sys
from bleak import BleakClient

notify_char = "2ea78970-7d44-44bb-b097-26183f402401"


def notify_callback(handle: int, data: bytearray):
    print(f"{handle}: {data}")

async def main(address):
  async with BleakClient(address) as client:
    if (not client.is_connected):
      raise "client not connected"

    services = await client.get_services()

    await client.start_notify(notify_char,notify_callback)
    await asyncio.sleep(5.0)
    await client.stop_notify(notify_char)

Comment: the device notification works in nRF connect application

Comment: I use windows 10  machine. will that be a reason why I dont get callback